# Выделение памяти под массив классов

Tags: память, c++

Подскажите, как в C++ можно выделить память под массив классов, причем так, что бы каждый элемент можно было определить не только типа данного класса, но и типа наследников исходного класса.
Т.е. есть к примеру класс cClassParent и два класса наследника cClassChild1 и cClassChild2. Как выделить память под массив cClassParent, что бы можно было i-й элемент массива переопределить как cClassChildN
пробовал, например

```
cClassParent* obj = new cClassParent[3];
obj[2] = cClassChild1();
```

не работает

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Через массив указателей на базовый класс.

```
Parent** array = new Parent* [20];

array[0] = new Parent;
array[1] = new Child;
```

Но тут почитайте про виртуальные члены (очень хорошо написано в Эффективном программировании Майерса). В общем, основных правила 2:

1. Всегда делать деструктор базового класса виртуальным.
2. Все методы, которые планируете переопределять, делать виртуальными.

П. 1 нужен для предотвращении всяких неприятностей, а п. 2 для обеспечения доступа к методам производного класса через указатель на базовый класс.